# How to calculate golang overflow?

Tags: go

I am a newbie to Golang

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var u uint8 = 255
    var m uint16 = 255
    fmt.Println(u, u-1, u*(u-1))
    fmt.Println(m, m+1, m*m)
}
```

OUTPUT

```
./g2
255 254 2
255 256 65025
```

I understand that I have overflow in the first case. But why did I get 2 as a result?

Comment: Because `255 * 254 = 64770` and `64770 % 256 = 2`.

Comment: ok,thanks,I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve already hinted at overflow, and in fact this is exactly what’s happening here. You already know what `u` and `u-1` are (255 and 254 respectively), so let’s multiply those together. This gives us 64770, or in binary:

```
64770       = 1111 1101 0000 0010
```

This result is 16 bits wide, but we’re storing it in a `uint8` which is only 8 bits wide. It is therefore truncated to the 8 *least significant* bits. Mathematically, this is equivalent to performing **64770 mod 2^8** or **64770 mod 256**. Programatically, it’s equivalent to performing `64770 & (1 << 7)` or `64770 & 256`:

```
64770       = 1111 1101 0000 0010
256         =           1111 1111
64770 & 256 = 0000 0000 0000 0010 = 2
```

However you chose to imagine this operation, the result is 2.